# Jquery Datepicker with MVC - Get date picked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have the following in my MVC View:

```
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDateCollected, new { style = "width:90px;" })
```

In query I have the following:

```
    $("#FromDateCollected").datepicker();
```

To get the selected date, I tried the following:

```
     var dt = $("#FromDateCollected").datepicker("getDate")

     alert(dt);
```

but getting:

```
    [object Object]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the date from the textbox value.

```
var dt = new Date(Date.Parse($('#FromDateCollected').val()));
alert(dt);
```

Comment: Thanks. This does not work for me though. When I do alert(dt) the alert doesn't even come up. If I do it with the Date.Parse it works. Any idea?

Comment: I've update the code, Date.Parse parses a date string and returns the number of milliseconds between the date string and midnight of January 1, 1970. You can create a date object from that.

Answer (score 1):

just get the value of text box

```
var dt = $("#FromDateCollected").val();
alert(dt);
```

If you want to get the selected date, when user select a date in the calendar, you can do that on the `onSelect` event

```
 $(function() {

   $('#FromDateCollected').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
           alert(dateText);
      }
   });

});
```

Working sample  http://jsfiddle.net/pDmjm/5/

EDIT : as per the comment,

`$("#FromDateCollected").datepicker("getDate")` will give you a Date object and `$("#FromDateCollected").val();` will give you a string with current value in the textbox. write the result to a console and you will see the result.

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/pDmjm/14/ (check firebug console after alerts)

Comment: Thanks. Question, I tried what you had above and it it shows the date just fine. Is dt a string or is it a date type? I tried the following to convert it to a date: var dt = Date.Parse($('#FromDateCollected').val()) 
but the alert doesn't even come up with I do alert(dt). Why is that?